# Javascript Context Menuwith AngularJS Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am creating a shift planner, here i've made a JS context menu and trying to display the shift via angular. On clicking on any table cell all the cells are getting updated is there any workaround for this? What am i doing wrong.
Plunker link :http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAWXlTsY0Z7SPeEVRtTe`

```
    <ul ng-repeat="s in shifts">
            <li  ng-click="select(s)" >{{s.title}}</li>
    </ul>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for when you change the select option, then you table data will changes

```
<select class="filter" name="show-filter" ng-model="selectedDept" 
    ng-options="d.title for d in departments" ng-change="changeTable()">
  </select>
```

in Script :

```
$scope.changeTable - function(){    
  $scope.selectedDept // selected value
  //get the results and append here
}
```

Comment: The filters are actually disabled for now...i'm just trying to get the context menu to work for every relative cell...Thank you anyways